# How to dynamically load/source a record for type list/record in netsuite sublist using suitescript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

There is two dropdown list/record in a sublist and I want to change the second dropdown list/record type value(load a new record type) based on the selection of the first one.

Eg: A and B are list/record type(record) dropdowns, A is my main list with values from a main category record. What I want is not just sourcing and filer from one record. A contains 6 main category values and this 6 main category has 6 sub categories with multiple values in it. This 6 sub categories I have created as 6 records, I want this to source it to B dropdown depending on the selection of A dropdown main category value.

I have many records as a subcategory and after choosing the main category I want to dynamically load the respective record in the dropdown. I have tried to load a record as a value and failed.

```
    if (sublistName === 'recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent' && sublistFieldName === 'custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_category') {
        alert(currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
            fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_category",
            line: currentLine
        }));
        var expCategory = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
            fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_category",
            line: currentLine
        });
        switch (expCategory) {
            case '1':
                alert(expCategory);
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: record.load({
                        type: 'customrecord_sony_exp_clm_food_bv', 
                        id: '349',
                        isDynamic: true
                        }),
                    line: currentLine
                })

                break;
    case '2':
        // I want to load another record if the main category is 2.
     break;

default:
                    alert("BREAK:::::::::"+expCategory);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The Below code is updated as the value for setCurrentSublistValue tag is now pointing to the custom record id. Still It doesn’t load the record to the subcategory dropdown in the list.

```
define(['N/search','N/record'], function (s,record) {

// Client Script global variables.
var allowSave = true;
var firstItemNegative = false;
var firstItemParentID = -9999;

function fieldChanged(context) {

    var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;    // Current opened record.
    var sublistName = context.sublistId;          // The internal ID of the sublist.
    var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;       // The internal ID of the field that was changed.
    var currentLine = context.line;               // Line number (first line has value = 0) of Item User is on.

    // Run when the Item field of the inventory sublist changed.
    // Item for some reason does not fire a change event, so using item description instead.
    // This means the description has to be required for these types of items.
    //alert("sublistName##"+sublistName+"&&&&&"+"sublistFieldName##"+sublistFieldName+"&&&&&"+"currentLine##"+currentLine+"&&&&&");
    if (sublistName === 'recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent' && sublistFieldName === 'custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_category') {
        var expCategory = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
            fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_category",
            line: currentLine
        });
        switch (expCategory) {
            case '1':
                alert(expCategory);
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: 'customrecord_sony_exp_clm_accommodation',
                    line: currentLine
                })

                break;
            case '2':
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: 'customrecord_sony_exp_clm_mob_comm',
                    line: currentLine
                })
                break;
            case '3':
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: "customrecord_sony_exp_clm_food_bv",
                    line: currentLine
                })
                break;
            case '4':
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: "customrecord_sony_exp_clm_transportation",
                    line: currentLine
                })
                break;
            case '5':
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: "customrecord_sony_exp_clm_staff_sales",
                    line: currentLine
                })
                break;
            case '6':
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: "customrecord_sony_exp_clm_other",
                    line: currentLine
                })
                break;
            default:
                    alert("BREAK:::::::::"+expCategory);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your record that you want to set already exists, you can use `setCurrentSublistValue` with value as the internalId of the said record.
But if the record does not exists, you can insert a line in sublist and then set the fields on the sublist using the same `setCurrentSublistValue`
 and at last when you are done, commit the line and new record will be automatically created.

Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273171484.html) out on how to set sublist value.

Comment: I am using N/record modlue. is this the correct way to load a record to dropdown. i am getting an error message saying "hat record does not exist"

Comment: what do you mean by load a record to dropdown? Do you want to set/select some other record on sublist-line?

Comment: i want to set another record to the second dropdown depsending on the first dropdown list.

Comment: so the record already exists right? If yes then you need to use `setCurrentSublistValue`. If no then you need to insert line and then set values on the fields and at last commit line, this automatically create a new record in the background and it will be assigned/select on the current line

Comment: Actually what I am trying is to update dropdown in the sublist depending on another dropdown in the same sublist. Main category dropdown and subcategories dropdown(Depending on the main category dropdown I want to load subcategory values from different records). So my question is how to change/set/select a record to dropdown in the sublist.

Comment: As  mentioned in above comment, you need to use `setCurrentSublistValue`. Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273171484.html) out for further reading

Comment: setCurrentSublistValue with this we can update the values of dropdown list with already configured record. What I want is to change the record itself. Can you please check my code and help me if this is the right way to do this

Comment: Yes, as long as the record exists, you could set is using `setCurrentSublistValue` and pass its recordId for value property.

Comment: Yes the one I have mentioned above

Comment: if you can check my above code in the switch i am already using currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "recmachcustrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_parent",
                    fieldId: "custrecord_sony_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry",
                    value: record.load({
                        type: 'customrecord_sony_exp_clm_food_bv', 
                        id: '349',
                        isDynamic: true
                        }),
                    line: currentLine
                })

Comment: If you check in my above comment, I specifically mentioned to pass recordId of the custom record in value property and not he complete record. Also you should check out the link I have mentioned in answer or the comment on how setCurrentSublistValue works.

Comment: As your suggestion i have added the value tag with record ID to show load diffrent record to the type List/Record in the sublist. can you help me with this

Comment: You have a custom record with a field as Parent, so you will need to update custom record itself.  You could use `submitFields` or `record.load` with `record.save` from **record** module to set value of current record in the reference field.

Comment: While creating the record type(form for sublist) I have pre-assigned(mandatory to choose a record or list) a record to the list/record type. what I am looking is to dynamically switch/load/change record in list/record input type dropdown list.

Eng.: A form having two dropdown list A and B respectively. I’m using expense itinerary record type as a sublist for expense record(Main). A user will have to fill this expense itinerary record to add his expenses. Here I am using dropdown A to trigger/load/change dropdown B.

Comment: Let me see if I get this, you want to provide a dynamic list to user in second dropdown list based on user selection in first dropdown?

Comment: Yes, I am using record insted of list in dropdown

Comment: Yours original question was completely different for this. What you need is Sourcing and Filtering feature in NetSuite. Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n2839623.html) out on how to filter a field on another field. You need to do the same in your sublist field

Comment: My question is still completely correct, I will explain you more on this. In A and B list/record dropdowns, A is my main list with values from a main category record. What I want is not just sourcing and filer from one record. A contains 6 main category values and this 6 main category has 6 sub categories with multiple values in it. This 6 sub categories I have created as 6 records, I want this to source it to B dropdown depending on the selection of A dropdown main category value.